# How do I run a command automatically upon boot?

Tags: command-line, boot, startup

Currently my ubuntu setup is going directly to console. I have LXDE installed, and have to enter "startlxde" every time I restart the computer.

Is there a way to automatically run this command at startup?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have a display manager installed. This is what would normally start up X (the graphical server) and get you into a position where you can log in. The confiusing thing is how you ended up without `gdm` or `lightdm` in the first place.

If you're using 11.10, I suggest you run

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

That should install everything it needs in terms of start up scripts and should display something fancy for you on boot.

If you're on something before 11.10, swap out `lightdm` for `gdm`.

If you did this on purpose and you don't want a display manager and only want a single-user system without login protection, look into `nodm` which is a display manager that just spits you out on a desktop as a user. It's a bit more manual to set up though.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to look into downloading a display manager. The reason why I don't have one installed by default is because I am running a custom version hacked to run on the HP touchpad.

Comment: `nodm` might be perfect for you, but start out with an established one like `lightdm` or `gdm` to begin with.